# Bismillah or it's translation to begin the post with and And Allah Knows Best to end with

Tags: discussion

StackExchange sites are about "Just questions" "..and Answers". Salutation are not acceptable, that is established across the SE network, but what about "Bismillah" (and others form of it that come that come under the same category) and/or it's translations?

How does that conform to "Just questions" and "Answers", if they were to be acceptable? And if acceptable then I think it would be better that snapshot of a post that contained them be added in the [about](https://islam.stackexchange.com/about) page.

And what about post ended with "And Allah Knows Best"? I accept,with reservation (strictly speaking when it come to rules), that at some places like when in doubt etc, it is in place but in post where such is not the case why is it acceptable?

Comment: Inre the about page: Right now, there is exactly *one* question on this site which meets [the selection criteria](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947) for the demo question.

Answer (score 2):

One of the [major criticisms against greetings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950) is that, since the question preview isn't very long (~200 characters, I believe), greetings which inevitably take the first x characters of that preview just make it harder to recognize a good question from a bad one without needing to first load it in full.  It should be noted that this argument is often defended when it regards common English greetings, which are far shorter than the full *basmalah*.

That argument doesn't really apply to answers though, since (as far as I know) they don't have a preview.  Adding a greeting thus merely adds an extra line or two to the page.  This is not only (mildly) annoying because it just makes the page longer for no good reason, but it also has the additional problem of just looking...unprofessional.

That said, there more than sufficient Islamic basis for praising God before partaking in such writings.  There is also more than enough precedent in existing Islamic Q&A sites for including the *basmalah* and other forms of God-praising; unlike the *salam* — as a greeting it tends to make the site appear like a typical forum and/or discussion board which the Stack Exchange model very much isn't — I feel that adding such praises would not detract from the professional appearance of the site at all as long as they're of reasonable length and the post otherwise answers the question well.

Scholars on a number of professionally-run and successful Islamic Q&A sites (e.g. [IslamQA](http://islamqa.info/en), [Qibla Answers](http://spa.qibla.com)) frequently open with a form of praise such as the *basmalah* or *al-hamdulillah*, and close along the lines of "And Allah knows best."  Even then the opening and closing praises often only take an additional line each, while surrounding a substantial answer.

While I would still *personally* recommend against inclusion, just for the sake of brevity and making the actual answers that much easier to find, if the poster chooses to couch his answer in such forms of God-praising (as contrasted with greeting) I feel that that shouldn't be discouraged, at least not to the point that they be edited out after the fact.

However, I think they should still fall under the general "no greetings" guideline for *questions* due to the preview-space issues mentioned earlier.

---

In short:

- **Questions**: Do not include.
- **Answers**: Include at poster's discretion so long as they…

  - are short
  - look professional
  - don't distract from the answer

Comment: Should the "praising" be of a certain size? For instance [this answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/35232/15201) has a h2-tag in the top and the end of the answer. I am not sure if I am right, but in a SEO point of view, that might not be the best idea *(except if you want to show up in first page in google for the search term "praise Allah", but the content wouldn't be about praising Allah though)* The search function at islam.SE might also get affected by this: i.e i search for praise and get 400 irrelevant q/a's.

Comment: @Kilise Is it short? Does it look professional? Does it distract from the answer? I looked at the linked post, and I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: By size I meant which HTML tag, for instance h1, h2 ,h3 or just a paragraph.